# Python Pandas - How to find rows where a column value is different from two data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, concatenation

I am trying to get rows where values in a column are different from two data frames.

For example, let say we have these two dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd    
data1 = {'date' : [20210701, 20210704, 20210703, 20210705, 20210705],
    'name': ['Dave', 'Dave', 'Sue', 'Sue', 'Ann'],
     'a' : [1,0,1,1,0]}

data2 = {'date' : [20210701, 20210702, 20210704, 20210703, 20210705, 20210705],
    'name': ['Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave', 'Sue', 'Sue', 'Ann'],
     'a' : [1,0,1,1,0,0]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

As you can see Dave has different values in column 'a' on 20210704, and Sue has different values in column 'a' on 020210705. Therefore, my desire output should be something like:

```
import pandas as pd    
 output = {'date' : [20210704, 20210705],
        'name': ['Dave', 'Sue'],
         'a_from_old' : [0,1]}

df_output = pd.DataFrame(output)
```

If I am not mistaken, what I am asking for is pretty much the same thing as `minus statement` in SQL unless I am missing some edge cases.

How can I find those rows with the same date and name but different values in a column?

### Update

I found an edge case that some data is not even in another data frame, I want to find the ones that are in both data frame but the value in column 'a' is different.

I edited the sample data set to take the edge case into account.
(Notice that Dave on 20210702 is not appear on the final output because the data is not in the first data frame).

Answer (score 1):

try left `merge()` with `indicator=True` then filterout results with `query()` then drop extra column by `drop()` and rename 'a' to 'a_from_old' by using `rename()`:

```
out=(df1.merge(df2,on=['date','name','a'],how='left',indicator=True)
        .query("_merge=='left_only'").drop('_merge',1)
        .rename(columns={'a':'a_from_old'}))
```

output of `out`:

```
    date        name    a_from_old
2   20210704    Dave    0
4   20210705    Sue     1
```

**Note:** If there are many more columns that you want to rename then pass:

`suffixes=('_from_old', '')` in the `merge()` method as a parameter

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! while I was trying, I found an edge case and updated my question.

Please guide me how to incorporate that.

Comment: @YunTaeHwang this is working in your edge case as well so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Another option but with an inner [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and keep only rows where the `a` from `df1` does not equal the `a` from `df2`:

```
df3 = (
    df1.merge(df2, on=['date', 'name'], suffixes=('_from_old', '_df2'))
        .query('a_from_old != a_df2')  # df1 `a` != df2 `a`
        .drop('a_df2', axis=1)  # Remove column with df2 `a` values
)
```

`df3`:

```
       date  name  a_from_old
2  20210704  Dave           0
4  20210705   Sue           1
```